# How to set value on nullable object using xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I trying to display nullable object. When variable is coming null to show 0.
My object is double? and when this object is null He not showing on display.

How can I set 0 on this object when coming null ?

My xaml code:

```
Label x:Name="SnowForecastFirstDay"   
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="4"
                   FontSize="15"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

My C# code:

```
double? snowForecastFirstDay = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue;

        if (snowForecastFirstDay == null)
        {
            SnowForecastFirstDay.Text = "SNOW: 0mm";
        }
        else
        {
            SnowForecastFirstDay.Text = "SNOW:" + weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue.ToString() + "mm";
        }
```

I try with this if/else statement but my label not displaying on the screen.
how is the right way object with null value to appear on the display?

Comment: use `snowForecastFirstDay.HasValue` to determine if a nullable type has a value

Comment: Can you give me example ?

Comment: `if (snowForecastFirstDay.HasValue)`

Comment: not work ;( i try with your way but the label not showing

Comment: where are you actually getting this data from?  Are you positive it actually has a value?

Comment: when it rains there is a value, when it does not rain the value is null, I want when the value is null to set 0 "zero" on the label.

Comment: Im getting data from openweathermap.

Comment: I don't see any snow fields in their sample data.  Again, I suggest you use the debugger to examine the **actual data** you are receiving to verify that it has a value and is the correct type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232121/discussion-between-ben-johnson-and-jason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the **null coalescing operator**.

```
double? snowForecastFirstDay = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue ?? 0;
SnowForecastFirstDay.Text = "SNOW:" + snowForecastFirstDay  + "mm";
```

Comment: I tried your way, but it didn't work again.. 
The object is double? I did it on purpose, not double because my debugger rumbles that I have null value. Is that the problem?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by " The object is double?" ?

Comment: The object type is double? not double

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers given I can guess that the issue is not with your nullable double not getting a value but with your label.
Give your label a default text and comment your programmatic alter of the value, make sur it is displayed.
Note : in your post you forgot the oppening tag "<" hope you didn't in your code.

```
<Label x:Name="SnowForecastFirstDay" 
                   Text="Default value for test"  
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="4"
                   FontSize="15"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```